# Template function call not working after boost library updates

Tags: c++, templates, boost

In Boost 1.54.0, the template function is defined as:

```
template<class Ch>
std::basic_string<Ch> trim(const std::basic_string<Ch> &s,
                           const std::locale &loc = std::locale())
{
...
}
```

In Boost 1.57.0, the template function is updated to:

```
template<class Str>
Str trim(const Str &s, const std::locale &loc = std::locale())
{
...
}
```

My function call which is working for boost 1.54.0 is:

```
void read_command_line(int argc,char** argv,...){

string text = boost::property_tree::detail::trim<char>(argv[i]);
}
```

Now after switch to Boot 1.57.0, the error message for my implementation is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'trim(char*&)
```

I see the argument variable is reference as '&s' for both version, why it gives the error above? And could you help for how I shall update my code and explains a little bit?

Comment: string text = boost::property_tree::detail::trim<char>(*argv[i]); 

Gives the error:
error: 'char' is not a class, struct, or union type

Comment: `s` is the *name* of the variable, not the *type*.

Comment: the `detail` namespaces in the boost libraries are not part of the public api - ie. you're not supposed to use them, and definitely not rely on their behavior not changing between versions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a template function and the boost developers seem to have anticipated that the template argument would be inferred from the function arguments. By explicitly supplying the arguments you broke this assumption.

Provide the type through the arguments:

```
auto text = boost::property_tree::detail::trim(string{argv[i]});
```

This should be compatible to the old and new interface.

The advantage of the new interface is that it supports all string-like classes, not just those derived from `std::basic_string`.

Answer (score 1):

The `detail` namespaces in the boost libraries are not part of the public api - ie. you're not supposed to use them, and definitely not rely on their behavior not changing between versions.

If you want trim functionality, have a look at these [`trim` functions provided in the Boost String Algorithms Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.trim_hpp).